# Refer to the same footnote multiple times in Pages '09

Tags: iwork-pages, iwork

I would like to refer to the same footnote multiple times in Pages '09.

What it does now, is create a new (identical except for the little number) footnote. So I have three or four identical footnotes which is a waste of space. it looks like this:

> These are the first<sup>1</sup>, second<sup>2</sup> and third<sup>3</sup> references, all numbers referring to their own (further identical) footnotes.

I would like to have it like this:

> These are the first<sup>1</sup>, second<sup>1</sup> and third<sup>1</sup> references, all numbers referring to **the same** footnote.

Comment: Is it a reference to a source or do you wish to give an explanation of something? In the first case, usually there is a sources list at the end of the document (not footnotes on the page) and the sources are referenced by brackets, like [1]. In the second case, style rules only require you to mention the footnote once, at the first occurence, so there's no need to use the same footnote multiple times.

Comment: @Roald van Doorn: I wish to give a specification. It is about a procedure how to specify certain medical conditions. Several of these need to be specified in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use cross reference - there is a special option in the cross reference box that allows you to reference with a footnote of an endnote.

Put your cursor at the position you want to have the reference inserted:

1. Click on Cross-Reference
2. In Reference type choose Endnote/footnote
3. Uncheck Insert as hyperlink box
4. In Insert reference to choose Endnote/Footnote (formatted)
5. Uncheck Include above/below box
6. In the box at the bottom choose the endnote/footnote you want to reference
7. Click Insert

Comment: Sorry, where exactly do you 'click on cross-reference'? I have looked through all menu options of Pages 5.2.2 and couldn't find a single mention of 'cross-references'.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually [no such support](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10092709?messageID=10092709#10092709?messageID=10092709) implemented into pages.

You would have to insert the number manually and superscript it, sad to say. The point is that the way you are trying to use it is improper, as I had to learn.